# NS_OPTIONS Bitmask Autogeneration

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums, bitflags

I have a large enum (for the sake of transparency 63 values), and I am now creating a NS_Options bitflag based on that enum. Is there a way that I can write this so that it will be flexible?

The main concerns I have with hardcoding it are:

- If I add/remove an enum, I will have to manually add/remove it in my bitflag.
- There is a lot of typing to generate these.
- My .h file is getting intensely long (because I like to use whitespace and adequate comments)

The only solution I've come up with thus far is:

```
#define FlagForEnum(enum) 1 << enum

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, ExampleEnum)
{
    Value1,
    Value2,
    ...
    ValueN
}

typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSNumber, ExampleEnumFlags)
{
    Value1Flag = FlagForEnum(Value1),
    Value2Flag = FlagForEnum(Value2),
    ...
    ValueNFlag = FlagForEnum(ValueN)
}
```

This is a barely adequate solution when I remove an enum (at least I get a compile error), and if the enum ordering gets changed, the flags' bitshifted position changes too (not that it truly matters, but it seems comforting). But it doesn't solve the 'this-is-a-lot-of-typing' problem, or the 'what-if-I-forget-to-add-a-flag' problem.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but Go has a neat approach to this: http://golang.org/ref/spec#Iota

Comment: How do you feel about a bit of code generation (e.g. a quick Python script)?

Comment: @JoshBleecherSnyder Code generation seems reasonable; definitely more reusable than my preprocessor code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a technique called [X Macro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro)

```
#define VALUES \
  VALUE_LINE(Value1) \
  VALUE_LINE(Value2) \
  VALUE_LINE(Value3)

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, ExampleEnum)
{
#define VALUE_LINE(x) x,
VALUES
#undef VALUE_LINE
}

typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, ExampleEnumFlags)
{
#define VALUE_LINE(x) x##Flag = 1 << x,
VALUES
#undef VALUE_LINE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly better (in terms of less typing) preprocessor `#define` solution. Although this still isn't as elegant as I'd like.

```
#define BitShift(ENUM_ATTRIBUTE)            (1 << ENUM_ATTRIBUTE)
#define CreateEnumFlag(ENUM_ATTRIBUTE)      ENUM_ATTRIBUTE##Flag = BitShift(ENUM_ATTRIBUTE)

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, ExampleEnum)
{
    Value1,
    Value2,
    ...
    ValueN
}

typedef NS_Options(NSUInteger, ExampleEnumFlags)
{
    CreateEnumFlag(Value1),
    CreateEnumFlag(Value2),
    ...
    CreateEnumFlag(ValueN)
}
```

This will create flags of the form `Value1Flag`, `Value2Flag`, ..., `ValueNFlag`.